# Libpcap not found in /usr/lib or /lib after apt installation

Tags: java, libraries, libpcap

I installed `jnetpcap` but it showed error that `libpcap.so` is not found, so I used

```
sudo apt-get install libpcap-dev
```

but when I `grep libpcap` in `/lib` and `/usr/lib` it is not there, am I missing something?

Answer (score 5):

If you need the library file, you don't have to install the development package. `libpcap-dev` is the package containing the files needed to develop and compile own programs using the functionalities offered by `libpcap`.

The dynamic library, the .so file, is located in a package which doesn't have `-dev` in its name.

On my system, Ubuntu 13.10, it is located in the `libpcap0.8` package.
So I did

```
$ sudo apt-get install libpcap0.8
```

and then looked if the .so file was well installed and ready to use by the system :

```
$ sudo ldconfig -p|grep libpcap
    libpcap.so.0.8 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcap.so.0.8
```

Please note that using `ldconfig -p` and searching for the library in its output looks more reliable to me because the .so file are not always installed in `/lib` or `/usr/lib` as you can see.
Of course, displaying the list of files provided by the package can show you in which directory the .so file is installed :

```
$ dpkg -L libpcap0.8
```

A last word, if the output of `ldconfig -p` doesn't show the library in its output, you can regenerate the list of shared libraries by typing :

```
$ sudo ldconfig
```

Comment: From redhat server I am getting error No package libpcap0.8 available.